# Reference .aspx property from .ascx

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Id like to reference a property in my .aspx from my .ascx.

Lets say my page class is:

```
public partial class MyAdminPage : System.Web.UI.Page
```

I was expecting I could do from my .ascx:

MyAdminPage  myPageInstance = (MyAdminPage)this.Page;

or

MyAdminPage  myPageInstance = this.Page as MyAdminPage;

Which I cant.

How could I reference my page class from the .ascx?

**Update 1**

Thanks for the replies.

I forgot to mention that the .aspx has a master page, and within the contentPlaceholder is where I have the .ascx control.

So from my .ascx if I do:
this.Parent --> I get a reference to "ContentPlaceHolder"
this.Parent.Parent --> I get a reference to "HtmlForm"
this.Parent.Parent --> reference to a 'MasterPage'.

I will not reuse the .ascx in any other .aspx pages just the one.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of user controls a little bit: a user control is a component which can be used in more than one webpage. it's similar to a Class in your object model.
Once your component has knowledge of the containing page- you can no longer use it in more than one page, and it's not really a user control. I think you have a couple of options: 1. give up the user control and just have it as a regular control inside your webpage, 2. re-design your user control so it doesn't have to have knowledge of the containing page.

Comment: @sJhonny thanks, in this case I will use this .ascx control only within a single .aspx page. I'll wont be reusing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sJohnny's comment is spot on, you should not be trying to modify parent (page) properties from the child (control).  One good way to handle this situation is for the child to raise an event when it needs the parent to act.  That way the parent can simply subscribe to the event and call whatever properties it needs at that time.  This way your user control is in no way tied to the implementation of this particular page.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
MyAdminPage myPageInstance = this.Parent as MyAdminPage;
if(myPageInstance != null)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MyAdminPage myPageInstance = 
     (MyAdminPage)this.parent;//in you ascx will do the task
```

also check : [Using parent page properties in user control](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2008/05/21/using-parent-page-properties-in-user-control.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `MyAdminPage myPageInstance = (MyAdminPage)this.Page;`