# Pass a value from aspx to ascx

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

I have a web page and it contains an user control inside of it. I have a property on the aspx page which gets set in the pageinit method and I need to that propery on ascx page.
How can I get it?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Tejs : I tried using hidden feilds it did not work. I also tried creating a class in the ascx page and then creating an instance of that class in aspx and assign values for some reason that does not work too.

Comment: Can't you simply assign from your page to a property on the User control? aka `MyProperty = "blah"; MyUserControl.SomeProperty = MyProperty;`

Comment: Create a public property in your user control. Assign it a value when appropriate in your aspx code behind.

Comment: @Pinu: Update your question and give examples of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a public property inside the ascx and set it at the same time you set in the aspx page.

Just to let you know, PreInit is a [EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w2tb12s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) not a method.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyAdminPage myPageInstance = this.Parent as MyAdminPage;
if(myPageInstance != null)
{
...
}
```

There has been a few questions on this.

[Reference .aspx property from .ascx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621512/reference-aspx-property-from-ascx)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest options are as follows:

1. Use a public variable and access it from the parent page.
2. Assign the variable to a hidden field on the ascx front end. A field like this: `<asp:HiddenField ID="ascxField" runat="server"  />` .

The example below is for #1, but #2 is almost the same.

Example #1:

**Aspx page:**

*Front end:*

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Admin" TagName="MyUserControl" Src="~/UserControls/.../MyUserControl" %>
```

...

```
<Admin:MyUserControl ID="MyUserControl" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Visible ="false" />
```

*Code Behind:*

```
 this.MyUserControl.Variable1 = 1;
 this.MyUserControl.Variable2= "value";
```

**Ascx page:**

*Code Behind*

```
public int Variable1 { get; set; }
public string Variable2 { get; set; }
```